# Prevent MouseUp when click starts outside of object

Tags: events, actionscript, mouseevent

I have Sprite object that is a poker chip. When the user clicks it the bid increase. I am increasing the bid on the `MouseUp` event. But if the user starts a click outside of the object/chip and then drags the mouse over the chip and does `MouseUp`, it fires the function mapped to `MouseUp`. How can I prevent it from firing if the click starts outside of the object.

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pressChipDown)
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, pressChipUp)
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, pressChipOut)



private function pressChipDown(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        super.x = startX + 5;
        super.y = startY + 5;
    }

    private function pressChipUp(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        increaseBid();
        super.x = startX;
        super.y = startY;
    }

    private function pressChipOut(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if(e.buttonDown) //if mouse button is down, move chip back but dont increase bid
        {
            pressChipUp(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT as MouseEvent)
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On roll over, start listening to mouse down and mouse up, if up before down, it's a "fake"

this.addeventlistener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onOver)

...

Comment: How do I start listening to MouseDown and MouseUp from there?

Comment: Just as you would in any other place. addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onReleased)

Comment: The class is already listening for MouseDown and MouseUp. It wouldn't do me any good to start listening again.

Comment: yeah, that's what I mean, you start listening when over, not initially.

Comment: you could also add a bool flag on mouseOver and reset it on mouseOut, and only accept clicks if bool flag is true